# scala: programmatically changing functions

Tags: scala

Consider the following snippet:

```
  def fun1(x:T): String = // something here 

  var grandFun = { 
    t: T => Map('key1 -> fun1(t))
  }
```

The question, is it possible to **programmaticlly** add a new function, to the map inside `grandFun`?
Essentially, fill out the following function:

```
def addFunToMyGrandFun(fun: T => String): Unit = { 
   // add fun go the `grandFun`
}
```

such that give:

```
def fun2(x:T): String = // something here
```

after running `addFunToMyGrandFun(fun2)`, `grandFun` gets updated to the following:

```
var grandFun = { 
  t: T => Map('key1 -> fun1(t), 'key2 -> fun2(t))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could define a map outside your function which only stores the functions. You could then use this map inside your function and apply the functions inside the map to get the desired map.

If you use a `mutable.Map`, you can add new functions to the map. Calling `toMap` on a `mutable.Map` returns an `immutable.Map`.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => MutableMap}

val functionMap = MutableMap.empty[Symbol, T => String]
val grandFun = (t: T) => functionMap.mapValues(f => f(t)).toMap
```

If for example `T` is an `Int` :

```
val yourMap = MutableMap.empty[Symbol, Int => String]
val grandFun = (n: Int) => functionMap.mapValues(f => f(n)).toMap

yourMap += 'key1 -> ((_: Int).toString)
grandFun(5) // Map('key1 -> 5)

yourMap += 'key2 -> ((_: Int).toString * 5)
grandFun(10) // Map('key2 -> 55555, 'key1 -> 5)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I will try this further to see things are working fine.

Comment: Works great so far! Any idea on this marginal question? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772695/scala-converting-map-of-functions-to-function-of-maps

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with your keys just being `String`s rather than symbols, then I think something like the following class should encapsulate your intent:

```
case class GrandFun[T,R](funs: Map[String, Function1[T,R]], count: Int) {

  def addFun(fun: T => R) = {
    val key = s"key$count"
    GrandFun(funs + (key -> fun), count + 1)
  }

  def apply(t: T) = funs mapValues { fun => fun(t) }
}

object GrandFun {
  def apply[T,R](): GrandFun[T,R] = new GrandFun(Map.empty[String,Function1[T,R]], 0)
}
```

Example use:

```
scala> val gf = GrandFun[Int, String]
gf: GrandFun[Int,String] = GrandFun(Map(),0)

scala> val gf1 = gf.addFun(fun1)
gf1: GrandFun[Int,String] = GrandFun(Map(key0 -> <function1>),1)

scala> def fun1(t: Int): String = t.toString
fun1: (t: Int)String

scala> def fun2(t: Int): String = (t+2).toString
fun2: (t: Int)String

scala> val gf1 = gf.addFun(fun1)
gf1: GrandFun[Int,String] = GrandFun(Map(key0 -> <function1>),1)

scala> val gf2 = gf1.addFun(fun2)
gf2: GrandFun[Int,String] = GrandFun(Map(key0 -> <function1>, key1 -> <function1
>),2)

scala> gf2(4)
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(key0 -> 4, key1 -> 6)
```

Note that I chose to make `GrandFun` immutable, but you could also go with a mutable form, such as:

```
class GrandFun[T,R] {
  private var funs = Map[String, Function1[T,R]]()
  private var count = 1

  def addFun(fun: T => R) {
    val key = s"key$count"
    count += 1
    funs = funs + (key -> fun)
  }

  def apply(t: T) = funs mapValues { fun => fun(t) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you see any pros and cons compared to Peter Neyens's answer? It seems like his answer is simpler. Or am I missing anything?

Comment: Shadowlands first immutable `GrandFun` is nice way to solve your problem in a more functional way, than mine using a mutable map. Making `GrandFun` a subclass of `(T => Map[String, String)])` would make it more clear that `GrandFun` is essentially a function.

Comment: As @PeterNeyens notes, my solution is more functional in style. I like the idea of marking it as a subclass of `(T => Map[String, R])`. As to simplicity, then yes, Peter's solution is simpler, but if you found you had a use case for a "removeFun" method, or "applyByKey" to get the result of one function determined by its key, and so on, then building out the class (maybe as a reusable library) could become worth the extra initial effort. Also, add in "map","flatMap", "filter", etc and it can turn into a full monadic construct. All depends on how your code evolves.